# Stripping unused library functions / dead code from a static executable

Tags: gcc, arm, ld, compiler-optimization, avr-gcc

I'm compiling code for an ARM Cortex-M0 mcu with GCC `arm-none-eabi-g++` (4.8.3).
All is fine, but I noticed that when I include and use any function from `cstdlib`, all functions from that file are included as well. How to get rid of them?

I'm calling `malloc()` and `free()` only, but the resulting ELF has `system()` and `isatty()` machine code as well.

The mcu has only 32kB flash, so ~0.7kB ballast matters, especially if this keeps happening for other headers.

Right now I use `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` for compiling and `-Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--static` while linking, as follows:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -c --std=c++11 -Os -I. -Ilpc1xxx -Idrivers -Wall -mthumb \
  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fmessage-length=0 -mcpu=cortex-m0 \
  -DTARGET=LPC11xx -fno-builtin -flto -fno-exceptions -o main.o main.cpp
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c --std=c11   -Os -I. -Ilpc1xxx -Idrivers -Wall -mthumb \
  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fmessage-length=0 -mcpu=cortex-m0 \
  -DTARGET=LPC11xx -fno-builtin -flto  -o core_cm0.o lpc1xxx/nxp/core_cm0.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc -nostartfiles -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -Wl,--gc-sections -flto \
  -Os -Wl,--static -T lpc1xxx/memory.ld -o firmware.elf main.o core_cm0.o  \
  libaeabi-cortexm0/libaeabi-cortexm0.a LPC11xx_handlers.o LPC1xxx_startup.o
```

Edit: **Warning:** The `-flto` flag in my example is wrong – somehow it discards interrupt routines.

The result is that when I do `arm-none-eabi-objdump -t firmware.elf`, I get among others:

```
00000fbc g     F .text  0000002c _isatty
00001798 g     F .text  00000018 fclose
00000e4c g     F .text  00000030 _kill
00000e7c g     F .text  00000018 _exit
00000fe8 g     F .text  00000050 _system
```

These functions are clearly redundant (and quite useless on mcu at all), yet GCC keeps them in the executable. There are no calls to them, these symbols are not referenced anywhere. It's effectively dead code.

How to get rid of them? Some extra compiler/linker flags?

---

**Edit:**

Minimal code to reproduce my problem:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
    [[gnu::unused]] volatile void * x = malloc(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Command used to compile that:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ --std=c++11 -Os -Wall -mthumb -ffunction-sections 
  -fdata-sections -fmessage-length=0 -mcpu=cortex-m0 -fno-builtin -flto
  -fno-exceptions -Wl,--static -Wl,--gc-sections -o main.elf main.cpp
```

And the `main.elf` file still has all stdlib bloat.

---

Comment: I don't think this should be tagged with avr-gcc since you are not using avr-gcc.

Comment: It does look like you provided the right compiler options to get rid of unused functions, so there must be something in one of the things you are linking in that uses those functions.  What exactly is LPC11xx_handlers.o anyway?  Are you sure it doesn't refer to those functions?  Maybe you could make a smaller test case and post the entire code needed to reproduce the problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `-ffunction-sections` is the right thing here, but the issue is that the object file that provides `malloc` and `free` is built without it (either `LPC11xx_handlers.o`, `LPC1xxx_startup.o` or some of the object files within `libaeabi-cortexm0.a`). In that case, the linker can only include the whole object file (or with `-Wl,--gc-sections`, the whole section) that contain functions you need.

The layout of functions in object files and sections is the only thing that actually matters, not which function is defined in the same header as another function.

So to fix your issue, rebuild your standard library files with `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`.

Comment: "the object file that provides malloc and free is built without it" - I should have thought of that myself!

Comment: Newlib has been build without the `-ffunction-sections` flag. I put too much faith in gentoo `crossdev`. Rebuilt newlib, went down from 11432B to 7384B.

Comment: Also there is an option available that I was just saw in gcc-arm-none-eabi.../share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/readme.txt about an option called --specs=nano.specs which tells the compiler and linker to use the size optimized newlib-nano, libstdc++_nano.a and libsupc++_nano.a.  Just adding this reduced my executable by 23%.